# Open Visual Studio solution with Roslyn

Tags: visual-studio, roslyn

I am trying to open a Visual Studio Solution with Roslyn to iterate through the projects and documents. I don't want to write to anything. With the code below NewSolution.Projects.count is always 0. Eventually I will want to get the SemanticModel for each document if that matters.

```
    Const SolutionPartialPath As String = "Visual Studio 2017\Projects\roslyn-master\src\Samples\Samples.sln"
    <TestMethod()> Public Sub UnitTest1()

        Dim myDoc As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        Dim SampleSolutionPath As String = Path.Combine(myDoc, SolutionPartialPath)

        Dim WS As AdhocWorkspace = New AdhocWorkspace()
        Dim SolInfo As SolutionInfo = SolutionInfo.Create(SolutionId.CreateNewId, VersionStamp.Create, SampleSolutionPath)
        Dim NewSolution As Solution = WS.AddSolution(SolInfo)

        For Each project As Project In NewSolution.Projects
            Debug.WriteLine(project.Name)
            If project.Name = "BasicAnalyzers" Then
                For Each document In project.Documents
                    Debug.WriteLine(document.Name)
                    ProcessOneFile(document)
                Next document
            End If
        Next project
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You never actually opened the existing solution file.
`SolutionInfo.FilePath` is used to identify the solution and to resolve relative paths, but never actually reads anything from disk (in particular, the core Workspaces API doesn't know anything about any particular file format).

To read `.sln` files and MSBuild-based `.cs-proj` files, you need `MSBuildWorkspace`.

Comment: Thanks, I am able to open the solution and iterate through the Projects but they have no documents in them.I looked at WS.OpenProjectAsync(project.FilePath).Result but that just gets an error about Document already in Workspace.

Comment: The program seems correct, The issues is the error" The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found." that does not appear unless I add  AddHandler MS_Workspace.WorkspaceFailed, Sub(sender As Object, e As WorkspaceDiagnosticEventArgs). Now I need to correct that issue.